# What is the meaning of this conversation between Dr. Hafez and the former Anck-Su-Namun?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mummy-returns

In the movie The Mummy Returns (2001), sequel to the highly famous The Mummy (1999), soon after  the protagonists capture the bracelet of Anubis from a place near the banks of the river Nile, we are shown with the scene showing a group of cults lead by Dr. Hafez searching for the remains of Imhothep. At that time, he will be greeted by 3 bandits who explain that the search for the bracelet was spoiled by the main leads, then the woman (claimed to be the current resurrection of Anck-Su-Namun, the lover of Imhothep) interrupts the conversation and says these:

> **Lead Bandit:** The opportunity passed us by.
>
> **Dr. Hafez:** We need that bracelet. And we need it before it opens.
>
> **Lady in black:** Enough. My dear Hafez, I told you I should have handled it.
>
> **Dr. Hafez:** I did not want your past history to cloud the issue.
>
> **Lead Bandit:** We know where it is. We'll take care of it.
>
> **Dr. Hafez:** No, we'll take care of it.

Now what did Dr. Hafez mean by the words "I did not want your past history
to cloud the issue."? Because there was no context about the lady that was explained in the previous movies!

Comment: Wasn't the lady the resurrected Anck-Su-Namun?  She had plenty of context in the original film.  She was the reason for Imhotep's mummification.  At least his love affair with her was.

Comment: She wasn't resurrected at the point in the movie. She just looked like her, waiting to be transferred souls by imhothep

Comment: I see.  I just always assumed that she was at least partially resurrected because she looked just like her.

Comment: Wasnt she the guardian of the bracelet along with Evelyn?

Comment: @DavidPilkington: That's a fact yes! but that was in her last incarnation. In the  scene I was mentioning she is just a normal person (probably a smuggler/thief) along with Dr. Hafez. Imhothep only later in the movie transfers the souls from the original person to the current using the 'Book of the dead'

Comment: in the beginning of the movie, we see Eve have a vision of being at the resting place of the bracelet before, due to her past life. perhaps, this was caused by being in that familiar place. the same thing would've/could've happened to Anuk.2 if she was near it. she would've lost her senses and been drawn into her past visions, potentially putting herself in danger before being resurrected by Imotep

Comment: @NicholasAysen: Good point! But how will Dr. Hafez know if whatever you said has happened and that seems no reason for him to prevent her from acquiring the bracelet. I felt `I did not want your past history to cloud the issue.` seems more like he didn't totally trust(maybe) her in completing the job!

Comment: @Inian its true he could not have known. the trust thing might actually be both ways. if history recorded the events, they know that Anuk is not to be trusted, having killed the Pharaoh. conversely, Hafez is also not to be trusted, being associated with such "savoury characters". and Anuk (more past life) would not trust him, because he wasn't so black or white in his trust. you couldn't really judge him. besides, Anuk would be totally lost in the modern age after resurrection, only wanting Imotep.